# Georeference vertical images on 3D wireframe

Tags: raster, 3d, ms-access

I would like to make a 3D wireframe model of a room in a building and then georeference images of the walls on the wireframe. Once I have the images rendering on the walls I want to insert points on the walls that are linked to an Access Database containing a range of attributes.

Can anyone assist with the workflow please.

Comment: what about the software you have not mention ?

Comment: What software? I’m using QGIS